# We also need to provide each component with a "key" vuejs

Tags: vue.js

```
<div id="app-7">
  <ol>
    <!--
      Now we provide each todo-item with the todo object
      it's representing, so that its content can be dynamic.
      We also need to provide each component with a "key"
    -->
    <todo-item
      v-for="item in groceryList"
      v-bind:todo="item"
      v-bind:key="item.id">
    </todo-item>
  </ol>
</div>
```

My question why We also need to provide each component with a "key" where any example that can help me to understand please

Comment: you could refer to this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Comment: well we all got in there at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Vue uses the key attribute to "track" each node rendered by a v-for loop, for performance purpose.
You can find more information here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Answer (score 0):

When Vue is updating a list of elements rendered with v-for, by default it uses an “in-place patch” strategy. If the order of the data items has changed, instead of moving the DOM elements to match the order of the items, Vue will patch each element in-place and make sure it reflects what should be rendered at that particular index. This is similar to the behavior of track-by="$index" in Vue 1.x.

that's from the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key)